# Send Sms from odoo application to mobile number

Tags: python, odoo

```
I have a problem with sending sms from odoo application to mobile number. here the console print the message but the message not sending in mobile number. Please help me how can I send message from button action in odoo. I added a button in form view and i need to send sms after clicking the button. I have declare a function with button name and I added the sms api. but i can not understand that how I send it in mobile number. Please help me.

def get_api_key(self, url='', username='', password=''):
    if not url:
        url = 'http://bulksms.skill.jobs/getkey'
    if not username:
        username = 'C2006884'
    if not password:
        password = ''
    r = requests.get(url="{url}/{username}/{password}".format(url=url, username=username, password=password))
    api_key = r.text.split(':')[1]
    print(api_key)
    return api_key
def send_sms(self, api_endpoint='', senderid='', **kw):
    if not api_endpoint:
        api_endpoint = "https://bulksms.skill.jobs/smsapi"
    if not senderid:
        senderid = "8809612436715"
    mobile = self.restaurant_id.mobile
    message = "{customer_name} has sent  a reservation in {restaurant_name} on . Please call {customer_mobile} for further info.".format(
        customer_name=self.customer_id.name,
        restaurant_name=self.restaurant_id.name,
        # date_and_time=self.time.strftime("%d %B %Y at %I:%M:%S %p"),
        customer_mobile=self.customer_id.mobile,
    )
    params = {
        "api_key": self.get_api_key(),
        "type": "text",
        "contacts": mobile,
        "senderid": senderid,
        "msg": message
    }
    r = requests.post(url=api_endpoint, data=params)
    self.state = 'sent'
    print(r)
    print(params)
    return True
```

[image]

I am trying to send message from odoo application to mobile number but the sms are not sending. Hello! I am trying to send message from odoo application to mobile number but the sms are not sending.I have a problem with sending sms from odoo application to mobile number. here the console print the message but the message not sending in mobile number. Please help me how can I send message from button action in odoo. I added a button in form view and i need to send sms after clicking the button. I have declare a function with button name and I added the sms api. but i can not understand that how I send it in mobile number. Please help me. I am suffering this problem very much. I can not find any resource about that. Here is the two function called get_api_key and send_sms. send sms is button name. and here the message i declare in send_sms. I am running odoo 14. Please help me to find out the problem. Here I attached a image. Its console log image.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do here is inherits the native sms module of odoo and modify it according to your needs, so you set up your API and so on. It has everything build already to send sms, batches and get error messages

Have a look there : https://github.com/odoo/odoo/tree/14.0/addons/sms
Or in your code ~/odoo/addons/sms

Comment: Brother here is the new model I create and I need to send sms through this model.

Comment: Yes of course, but what I suggested was that you use the inherit functionalities in your new model in order to get rid of the extra fuzzy stuff, all you need to do after that is rely on Odoo's greatness instead of reinventing the wheel. Thanks to this mechanism you will be able to use if you want the view components and the logic already developed in the framework but with your logic added to them.

Comment: How can I inherit default sms function. I can not inherit function yet. Can I inherit the sms default module in my button function send the params i declare in my function?

Comment: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/fr/developer/howtos/rdtraining/13_inheritance.html?highlight=inherit

Comment: hrere inherit the module not function

Comment: Ok I see, use this "style" in your imports.

from odoo.addons.stock.models.res_company import Company as ORIGIN_Company

Comment: which style i do not understand

Comment: Ok. You have to import the class like this --> from odoo.addons.sms.models.sms_sms import SmsSms as ORIGIN_Sms

Comment: then in your code use ORIGIN_Sms for the things you need and for extending functions :)